# Replace a pattern string to a structured string

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

I have a string like :

```
juices vegetables including {{smartpro=img:hippo-1.jpg,alt:abc,ht:217,wd:247,align:left}} wheatgrass, leafy greens, parsley, aloe vera & other herbs
```

Now here `{{smartpro=img:hippo-1.jpg,alt:abc,ht:217,wd:247,align:left}}` 
 replace with 
 `<img src="www.abc.com/media/images/hippo-1.jpg" alt="" width="247" height="217" align="left">`
 So the final string will be :

```
juices vegetables including <img src="www.abc.com/media/images/hippo-1.jpg" alt="abc" width="247" height="217" align="left"> wheatgrass, leafy greens, parsley, aloe vera & other herbs
```

Please help .
My attempt : `preg_replace('~\{{\{{(.+)\:(.+)\}}\}}~iUs','<img src="$2">$1/>',$string);`

Comment: Are the different parameters (img, alt, width, etc) always in the same order? Also, you don't want the `alt` paramenter?

Comment: @Jerry : yes . sorry updated the string . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = 'juices vegetables including {{smartpro=img:hippo-1.jpg,alt:Hippocrates,ht:217,wd:247,align:left}} wheatgrass, leafy greens, parsley, aloe vera & other herbs';
$pattern = '/(?:{{smartpro=img:)([^,]+)(?:,alt:)([^,]+)(?:,ht:)([^,]+)(?:,wd:)([^,]+)(?:,align:)([^}]+)(?:}})/i';
$replacement = '<img src="$1" alt="$2" height="$3px" width="$4px" align="$5"/>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you don't take care of `align` attribut and there're no needs to capture such a number og groups.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have `\{{\{{` in your regex. Is there perhaps `{{{{` in your string?

Also, `(.+):` will match everything until the last `:` because `.+` is greedy.

If your string is always in the same order, I would suggest using this:

```
{{[^}]*?(?:,?img:([^,}]+))?(?:,?alt:([^,}]+),)?(?:,?ht:(\d+))?(?:,?wd:(\d+))?(?:,?align:(\w+))?}}
```

And replace by:

```
<img src="www.abc.com/media/images/$1" alt="$2" width="$3" height="$4" align="$5">
```

This regex will also work if there are one or more parameters missing.

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/aE2rB8)

Comment: @Nikhil_K_R What do you mean it didn't work? What's the result you get?